# how to Drag a sprite in the world-canvas with mouse?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a freezer , contains some food , Its a bar at a canvas that I changed its type to world-Canvas .
but when I use the code below, the sprite didn't stick to mousePos

```
transform.localPosition = Input.mousePostion;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please follow the guideline before asking your question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Attach this code to your object :
1 - calculate the distance offset between your object and the camera (in World Space) 
2- select the object you  want to move by using ray-casts.
3- in Update Function, the picked object should follow the updated coordinates (offset + object world position)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DragAndDrop : MonoBehaviour
{  
    private bool _mouseState;
    private GameObject target;
    public Vector3 screenSpace;
    public Vector3 offset;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        // Debug.Log(_mouseState);
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {

            RaycastHit hitInfo;
            target = GetClickedObject (out hitInfo);
            if (target != null) {
                _mouseState = true;
                screenSpace = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (target.transform.position);
                offset = target.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 0));
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {
            _mouseState = false;
        }
        if (_mouseState) {
            //keep track of the mouse position
            var curScreenSpace = new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 0);

            //convert the screen mouse position to world point and adjust with offset
            var curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (curScreenSpace) + offset;

            //update the position of the object in the world
            target.transform.position = curPosition;
        }
    }


    GameObject GetClickedObject (out RaycastHit hit)
    {
        GameObject target = null;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast (ray.origin, ray.direction * 10, out hit)) {
            target = hit.collider.gameObject;
        }

        return target;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please always add some explanations to your code example .. this community is not ment to be a copy-paste code provider but rather make the OP actually learn something. Also remove any empty MonoBehaviour event (`Start` here) they are called anyway causing unnecessary overhead. Also the call to `Camera.main` could be stored once in start which would be cheaper than calling it every frame. If you have a `Screenspace Overlay` canvas the `z` will always be 0 anyway ;)

Comment: Thanks @derHugo for your recommendations